# How do i write Arabic text in the swiper.js file? PS: Not in the html output file but in a js script file

Tags: javascript, html, css, arabic, arabic-support

```
var loopSteps = [ 
 { title: 'Locate', details: 'In a hurry just find a Loop near by you.' },
 { title: 'Scan', details: 'Scan the Loop with your mobile or type in your code to activate.' },
 { title: 'Ride', details: 'Fasten your helmet, hop on and start your journey' }
 ]
```

In this part of script :  I just want the details text in arabic to be displayed in webpage.

Comment: How you type Arabic characters isn't really a programming issue. Set your system to use an Arabic keyboard layout, use a character picker app, etc.

Comment: @Quentin, I disagree!  For a specific language, the html header meta tag should be used.  See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Revised:
Set the editor's encoding to utf-8.
`dir` - extra, if you want.

Original, withdrawn:
In `<head>`, add:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

or, more specific:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-6">
```

Should work.
Perhaps you would like to use `dir="rtl"` in elements, or even in the `<body>` tag.  The whole page will be right-to-left, including table cell order and side of scrollbars.

Make sure your save your editor files with utf-8 encoding (not ansi, etc...)

Comment: ISO-8859 is **not** more specific, it is legacy. There's no good reason to use ISO-8859 in the 21st century.

Comment: The OP is asking how to write the text. This doesn't really address that. Especially since UTF-8 is the default almost everywhere.

Comment: @iAmOren  - Are you telling to add the <head> tag in script.js file??

Comment: No - in the HTML: `<html><head><title>some title</title><meta ....></head><body dir="rtl">....</body></html>`, but as pointed out and after my retraction - it seems as it's the standard in html5 - so it's not necessary.  If you write in Arabic in the text editor for the `.js` file - does it work?  I use NotePad++ where I chose `Encoding` = `UTF-8`.

Comment: "Standard" language for HTML will add consecutive `<td>`s left to right as in English, if you set the whole `body`'s `dir=rtl`, the consecutive `<td>`s will be added right to left = will give it a more "Arabic" feel.  That's why I code for English, and, if I'm asked to do Hebrew version (also right-to-left language) - it's a "pain" I try to avoid...  Look into the source code of Arabic web pages and see what they do - that's what I did at the beginning - although, some of them are horrible...  The solution for Arabic is most likely in your editor = have you tried NotePad++?  I really like it!

Comment: @iAmOren I have already wrote arabic contents in html file. But some text which is mentioned above in snippet comes from an external javascript file. when its output is in html page it shows english. I want to write the javascript file with some contents in arabic.

Comment: I don't understand: just write in Arabic wherever you want...
Well, inside quotes/in a String...
Just override that var: `loopSteps = [ 
  { title: "حدد", details: "في عجلة من أمرنا مجرد العثور على حلقة بالقرب منك." },
  { title: "مسح", details: "امسح الحلقة باستخدام هاتفك المحمول أو اكتب الرمز الخاص بك للتنشيط." },
  { title: "اركب", details: "اربط خوذتك وانطلق وابدأ رحلتك." }
]`.